# If one has a heter to do something unusual, must one do so discreetly?

Tags: halacha, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, marit-ayin

If one has a heter to do something unusual, must one do so discreetly? I am essentially asking whether marat ayin concerns are relevant to this type of situation.

(As for "Why wouldn't they be?"--I don't know. They might well be. I am searching for a definitive answer.)

Comment: How do you know that it is unusual? Perhaps it is pretty usual. Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: My understanding of marit ayin is that it applies to something that is prohibited, and if people saw you do it, they would consider it permissible. If you are the "exception", others watching you wouldn't know about this, so they can still be misled. Thus, it seems that "yes" is the answer to your question. As a matter of fact, I don't think a competent rav would give you a heter unless he knew that you COULD keep it private, unless, of course, there is no other means to do that.

Comment: If I were paskening for someone, I would be aware of the issue of the heter I am giving and also tell the person if they need to do it privately or not as well. Wouldn't any Rav do that?

Comment: People who are allowed to eat on fasts can't eat in front of others, but that's less maris ayin than loeg larosh (basically, a prohibition against doing things another can't, so they don't feel bad).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61297/marat-ayin-to-improve-appearance-of-action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is addressed in Halichos Shlomo on the laws of Yom Kippur chapter 5 siff 15, quoting the Minchas Shlomo Tinyana siman 53 #3. 
I'll try my best to translate.

"A sick person can wear leather shoes even if his sickness is not discernable, and there is no concern for Maris Ayin. However he should limit his unnecessary walking because of Lazus Sfasayim (people yapping)".

In the Dvar Halacha section the explenation is given that "Maris Ayin in Shas is concerning an allowed act which people might think is one which is not allowed, therefore it is Assur. Like eating fish blood, or nut milk with meat. As opposed to this sick person, this leather shoe is actually not allowed to be worn, it is only allowed due to his sickness, we do not find Maris Ayin in a case like this, just like one who cooks for a deathly ill person on Shabbos does not have to publicize why what he is doing is allowed. 
 In any case, being that at least it is certainly allowed in private as the mishna in Yoma 73b allowed a woman in labor to wear shoes, and since any act which was forbidden to do publicly is also not allowed to do privately even in one's inner rooms, we can apply the opposite logic, any act which is allowed in private, is also allowed publicly.

However it is simple that it is not proper to bring oneself into suspect, and many Takanos were made because of chshad, so therefore one should certainly limit his walking due to the yammering. But again, this has nothing to do with Maaris Ayin and it is certainly allowed to go to shul and such."

An aside. The footnote there #75 quotes the aforementioned tshuva as using this logic for allowing wigs even when it is hard to tell they are wigs.

Answer (score 1):

“Unusual” is not the criterion for maris hoayin. 
As [he.wikipedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9F) points out,

> מראית עין הוא דין הלכתי  האוסר לעשות פעולות מסוימות שבהן כשלעצמן אין
>   כל חטא, אך הן עלולות להיראות כאילו יש בהן חטא, או ליצור את  הרושם
>   שפעולות אחרות , שיש בהן איסור, הן מותרות.
>
> Maris hoayin forbids us to do something which intrinsically is not a
>   sin, but which might appear as a sin or give the impression that
>   something which is forbidden is allowed.

But we know

> אף שהאיסור על מראית עין נובע מחשש מה יחשוב חברו שיראה זאת, האיסור תקף
>   גם כאשר אין חשש "כזה: "אמר רב יהודה אמר רב: כל מקום שאסרו חכמים
>   מפני מראית העין - אפילו בחדרי חדרים אסור
>
> Source בבלי, מסכת ביצה ט א, מסכת שבת סד ע"ב ועוד.
>
> Even though the issur of maris hoayin stems from the concern of what
>   someone who sees might think, the issur operates even where there is
>   no concern for that because Rav Yehuda says in the name of Rav that
>   wherever Chachomim stopped an activity because of maris hoayin they
>   forbade it even in one's innermost chamber (where no-one could see).

Therefore:

If one has a heter to do something **unusual**, whether it may be done discreetly is a question for the Rav who gave the heter. Maris hoayin does not apply.

If the Rav says there is a question of maris hoayin, he will have to explain why it is not    forbidden in all circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, interesting answer, but I have some questions. First of all I should say that my original question was about something where a rov decides you are, according to Torah, allowed to do something that perhaps most people are not allowed to do because their circumstances are more mainstream. This would seem to fulfill the conditions of your first quote, where maris hoayin is defined, but not your second -- because the premise is that you have already been given a rov's permission to do such a thing. +

Comment: In the context of your two quotes, it seems that there is no solution to my question except "don't do it" (which contradicts the premise). I really don't know how to make sense of it. ... Also, I don't see from your answer why "maris hoayin does not apply," since the circumstance I am describing exactly fits the definition in your first quote.