# Marat Ayin to improve appearance of action

Tags: marit-ayin

If one is doing something in public which is normally forbidden, but is permitted because of special circumstances, is he obligated to make it appear not forbidden?

EG: A lunatic threatens to kill your family unless you go into the schul and drink a glass of blood. If you tell people why you are doing it, he will kill them anyway. He is obviously not doing this out of antisemitism because he asks a non-Jew to do a similar task. Should you put some fish scales around so people think you are drinking fish blood?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question; someone is doing something that is, in fact, completely forbidden (but for a good reason) [like drinking animal blood], and you want to know if this person would have to present a false-but-plausible reason [fish scales=fish blood] so as to get around issues of מראית עין?

Comment: Marit ayin is to prevent people from thinking your permitted action is forbidden. AFAIK, the halacha of marit ayin doesn't have anything to do with actually forbidden actions. Your example is ambiguous, though, because doing something to save your life is permitted. Are you asking about that case or about the case where you're eating McDonald's just because you want to? Your title suggests the latter.

Comment: This question is when the thing is permitted but you have to pretend it is permitted for a different reason. The next question is whether a sinner would get some kind of credit for toning down his public desecration.

Comment: I have edited the question to try and make it a bit clearer. Please [edit] and/or let me know if my edit does not represent your question accurately.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57269/if-one-has-a-heter-to-do-something-unusual-must-one-do-so-discreetly I Think the answer there would answer this as well. It's probably a dupe. BTW i don't think putting a fish scales next to the blood would help in any case. Just like nuts next to breast milk. Those items are meant to prove the truth, not create a lie.

Comment: @user6591 The way I understand the OP, that's exactly the question. If you can source your assertion, that would be an answer.